# Three.js matcap material being washed out

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to implement a matcap shader on a 3D scene based on this: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_matcap.html

But when I do, it becomes washed out: http://snow3.co.uk/bigger-picture/goo/index.html

See my original map-cap for comparison: [image: matcap]
<sub>(source: [snow3.co.uk](http://snow3.co.uk/bigger-picture/goo/img/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg))</sub>

I'm not sure if i'm importing the image wrong or I'm blind to some kind of colour transform.

Comment: Try to set the `encoding` property of your texture to `THREE.sRGBEncoding` similar to the official example.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had gammaOutput (renderer.gammaOutput = true;) enabled in the renderer which was causing it! All fixed.